# docker-compose ps does not show container when generated with multiple Compose configurations

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to share Compose configurations between different projects using the same postgres database and redis server. For that, I have three different Compose configurations.

- `./docker-compose.base.yml`
- `./apps/app1/docker-compose.extended.yml`
- `./apps/app2/docker-compose.extended.yml`

I create and start the containers with the following command:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f apps/app1/docker-compose.extended.yml -f apps/app2/docker-compose.extended.yml up -d`

All the services in three configuration files are in the same network: `myapp-backend`. All services (`postgres, redis, elasticsearch, kafka, zookeeper, app1, app2`) run without any problems, except one catch. `app2` does not show up when I write `docker-compose ps` or it does not stop when I type `docker-compose down`.

```
Creating network "myapp_myapp-backend" with the default driver
Creating myapp_postgres_1      ... done
Creating myapp_zookeeper_1     ... done
Creating myapp_redis_1         ... done
Creating myapp_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Creating myapp_kafka_1         ... done
Creating myapp_app1_1          ... done
Creating myapp_app2_1          ... done
```

```
docker-compose ps
           Name                          Command               State                  Ports                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
myapp_elasticsearch_1   /usr/local/bin/docker-entr ...   Up      127.0.0.1:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp  
myapp_kafka_1           start-kafka.sh                   Up      127.0.0.1:9092->9092/tcp            
myapp_postgres_1        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      127.0.0.1:5434->5432/tcp            
myapp_redis_1           docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp                            
myapp_app1_1            /bin/sh -c bundle install  ...   Up      127.0.0.1:3000->3000/tcp            
myapp_zookeeper_1       /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/sshd  ...   Up      2181/tcp, 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

As you can see, `app2` service does not show up here. But it shows up on `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
75bc1704c559        myapp_app1               "/bin/sh -c '(bundle…"   33 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       127.0.0.1:3020->3000/tcp               myapp_app1_1
4ab2294f7a2c        myapp_app2               "/bin/sh -c 'bundle …"   33 minutes ago      Up 32 minutes       127.0.0.1:3000->3000/tcp               myapp_app2_1
...
```

I can share the compose files if necessary, but I cannot understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose ps` doesn't remember the full stack of Compose files you initially ran `docker-compose up` with.  You need to repeat all of the `-f` options on every `docker-compose` command.

If you don't want to repeat this, Compose also supports a [`COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_file) that is the same as the `-f` options, so you should also be able to:

```sh
export COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.base.yml:apps/app1/docker-compose.extended.yml:apps/app2/docker-compose.extended.yml
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose ps
docker-compose down
```

Answer (score 0):

> it shows up on docker ps:

That's part of a feature: Multiple Isolated environments on a single host.

Compose is using the project **app**_1 or _2 to isolate environments from each other. From the docs

> - on a shared host or dev host, to prevent different projects, which may use the same service names, from interfering with each other

The default project name is the basename of the project directory. And that's the reason you can see the output `myapp_app2_1` meaning `service_folder_servicenumber`

> You can set a custom project name by using the -p command line option or the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable.

[Multiple isolated environments on a single host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host)